# From where is this thevenin equation derived?

Tags: thevenin

The equation is:

\$I_{in} = \frac{V_{th} - V_{in}} { R_{th}}\$

This equation is from a one-port network.

[image]

Variables:

I = input current

Vth = thevenin voltage

Vin = input voltage

Rth = thevenin resistance

Comment: Where is the schematic?

Comment: @dirac question edited.

Comment: You added a single line, without a schematic. What did you miss about "where is the schematic"?

Comment: @Jashazun I'm sorry. Reedited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the equivalent circuit in the situation you're asking about

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsbzBo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

"X" is whatever device is outside the device being studied. It could be a source, a resistor, or anything else.

Regardless of what is connected to the port, if the input voltage is \$V_{in}\$, then you can see the voltage across the thevenin equivalent resistor is \$V_{in}-V_{th}\$, so the input current can be obtained from Ohm's law as

$$\frac{V_{in}-V_{th}}{R_{th}}.$$

Which, incidentally, means there is a sign error in the formula you presented.